# Como puedo pasar argumentos con el PageRouteBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un PageRouteBuilder, para hacer una animación entre dos páginas, pero me gustaría saber la manera de pasar los argumentos a la siguiente página.

Answer (score 0):

Los parámetros se lo pasas a tu widget no al `PageRouteBuilder`, de la siguiente manera:

```dart
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (_, animation1, ___) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation1,
            child: TuWidget(
             param1: 'Tu_param1',
             param2: 'Tu_param2',
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```